# Hypothesis testing - comparing data with a function

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I am a beginner in statistics. My problem is as follows: I have a set of $N$ observations $\{(x_i,y_i,e_i)\}$, where $e_i$ is the error in the $i^\mathrm{th}$ observation. The individual observations were calculated as averages within bins of raw data, and the errors as square-roots of the bin variances.

I also have a function $f(x)$. Now, I would like to **quantify** how good a fit the function $f$ is to the observations. Also using $f(x) = 0$, I would like to quantify how likely it is that the observations are just random, 0 mean noise.

In my data, I see, among a lot of noise-looking, equally positive and negative values, a long sequence of positive values. I would like to quantify how unlikely its occurrence is and whether it's real or not.

Could you please help me with that or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
-SSF

Comment: you talk about "the" error, yet there are two variables $x,y$...what are these variables? How are they used to computer the error? Why is $f$ only a function of $x$?

Comment: I have a set of raw data in which measurements are parametrised by a precisely known value $x$, and a measured value $y$. Then, I bin several raw measurements together. I calculate the variance in their $y$ values, and use it's square-root to assign the error. The function $f$ is a function of the precisely-known coordinate $x$.

Comment: Ok, so you are regressing $x$ on $y$ using $f(x)$ and $e_i$ are your bin-wise standard deviations. The RMS error is a common measure for a regression.